# No OnClick Event firing after page is open for a few minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke

I've searched for this but didn't find any matching question:

I have a DNN Website hosted on a local server in our company, and I have my own modules, where I have some Forms with TextBoxes and Buttons. I now have the following problem:

When I enter text the time I open the page and click on the Button the OnClick-Event is fired and everything is okay. When I now have the page open for a few minutes and then click on a Button, the page just reloads and the Event is not firing.

I also tried to tebug this multiple times, but the debugger never stops at the OnClick Method if the page is open more than around 5 minutes (I don't know the exact timeout since I don't know which parameter is leading to this)

I am not sure if this is a Problem from IIS, ASP or DNN - so I hoped to find help here. If you need further information, please ask.

Since you asked for the Code, I reduced it to the important lines (total would be a few thousand lines):

**View.ascx**

```csh
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View.ascx.cs" Inherits="View" %>

...

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlGridView"></asp:Panel>

...
```

**View.ascx.cs**

```csh
public partial class View : FremdeBestellungenModuleBase, IActionable
{

...

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
...
                    BuildGrids(true);
...
            }
            catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
            {
                Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
            }
        }
...
        private void BuildGrids(bool all)
        {
...
                GridView gv = new GridView()
                {
                    ID = "GridView_" + role,
                    AllowSorting = true,
                    AutoGenerateColumns = false,
...
                };
...
                gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(Generated_GridView_RowDataBound);
                gv.Sorting += new GridViewSortEventHandler(GridviewBestellung_Sorting);
                if (Session["sort"] == null)
                {
                    Session[gv.ID] = gv.DataSource = list.Where(elem => elem != null).OrderByDescending(x => x.BestellNr).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    gv.DataSource = Session[gv.ID];
                }
                gv.DataBind();
                if (FindControl(gv.ID) == null)
                {
                    pnlGridView.Controls.Add(gv);
                }
            }

...
        protected void Generated_GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
...
                CheckBox chkManager = new CheckBox()
                {
                    ID = "chkManager"
                };

                e.Row.Cells[ManagerColumns.CheckUndHidden].Controls.Add(chkManager);
...

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {
...
                Button btnFreigeben = new Button()
                {
                    ID = "btnFreigeben",
                    Text = "Freigeben",
                    UseSubmitBehavior = false
                };
                btnFreigeben.Click += new EventHandler(BtnFreigeben_Click);
...
            }
        }

        protected void BtnFreigeben_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GridView gv = (GridView)btn.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;

            foreach (GridViewRow r in gv.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkManager = r.FindControl("chkManager") as CheckBox;
                if (chkManager.Checked)
                {
                //do stuff;
                BuildGrids(true);
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Insert page code to help users undestand.

Comment: You can use the DebugDiag tool to view the information in the action type for unconfigured first chance exceptions when the page open for a few minutes. About how to use the Debug Diagnostics Tool you can refer to this link: [Using Microsoft's Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.cantabilesoftware.com/support/DebugDiagTool).